# Open control panel from notepad in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, cmd, notepad, controlpanel

How to open control panel from notepad , I have stuck in a blue screen problem in windows 8.1. I tried a lot of things in advance options but nothing works . I tried system restore it pop up a message that an antivirus program is running , uninstall it and then continue. There is a option for cmd there  I open notepad from there , now I have to open control panel , how to open it?

Answer (score 1):

To open Control Panel you just have to type `control` in your open `CMD` window.

[image]

[Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/272460-programs-uninstall-using-command-prompt-windows.html) you can find a quickstep guide how to uninstall programms via command prompt in Windows 8.1
But you have to be **Administrator** to do this!
This also **won't work** if you are in **Startup and repair mode!**